# datasource binding to a dropdownlist with Entity object

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, c#-4.0, drop-down-menu

I am using Entity Data model in my project, and using Dropdownlists in several pages.  I am
assigning datasources to all the Dropdownlists and using entity objects. Everything was fine until now, and every Dropdownlist is getting value from entity object.

But problem is that it`s only first index value that is selected even though I selected "select any index value" from dropdownlist.

Here is the code snippet:

```
    PAYROLLEntities pe = new PAYROLLEntities();
    drplist_fromDept.DataTextField = "DEPARTMENT_NAME";
    drplist_fromDept.DataValueField = "DEPARTMENT_ID";
    drplist_fromDept.DataSource = pe.HR_DEPARTMENT;
    drplist_fromDept.DataBind();
```

Here is the code for Button "FindEmployee":

```
     GDView_Emplist.DataSource = trans.GetEmployee(drplist_fromDept.SelectedItem.Text,txt_empName.Text);
     GDView_Emplist.DataBind();
```

After compilation, even if I select the last indexed "department" and click on `find` button, `dropdownlist.selectedItem.text` is only returning the first index value.

Comment: I guess, you should operate with 'SelectedIndex' property, not 'SelectedItem'.

Comment: Make AutoPostBack=false on your dropdown

Comment: AutopostBack property is already set as false.

Comment: Make sure your DataBind code is not being executed on PostBack. Your button click will cause a postback which will rebind the dropdownlists. Just place the binding code within `if (!IsPostBack) { }`

Comment: Thank you very much  Derek Hunziker!  Now It`s working.